# What does the warning siren mean?

Tags: alien-crush-returns

Sometimes while playing Story Mode, a siren noise will go off while “WARNING!!” flashes on the screen. This happens intermittently at seemingly random times.

What does the warning siren mean?

[image: Warning!!]